# Bootstrap - Keep Div and Image on same row at same height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I the div on the left and the image on the right at the same height using Bootstrap?  They can stack when the screen width gets smaller, but at larger sizes they need to be equal.

[image]

```
<!-- main -->
<div id="main" class="row">
    <div class="left col-md-6">
        <h1>SCAQMD's Air Alerts lets you stay informed about air quality in your area.</h1>
        <div id="round">
            <img src="img/arrow.png" alt="arrow">
            <a href="http://aqmd.enviroflash.info/signup.cfm">Sign Up</a>
        </div>
        <div id="signup">
            <h2>SIGN UP TODAY</h2>
            <div><!-- line -->
            </div>
            <h3>to receive Air Alerts<br>Customized for you!</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right col-md-6">
        <img src="img/hero.jpg" class="pull-right img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- main -->
```

Comment: Please post a complete, working example of your code in a Snippet [mcve]

Comment: @Triode did you solve this problem???

Comment: Haven't solved it yet.

Comment: @Triode could you add some more info about the `css` affecting this. It would give more idea. Thank you

Comment: Just using the bootstrap classes at the moment.  It is possible that Bootstrap cannot do this feature.

This is another possibility, but I cannot figure out how to make the two elements equal width:

http://jsfiddle.net/5JU2t/141/

Comment: @Triode Do you want equal height or equal width? And create a jsfiddle for your code if possible to see the actual problem and add that into question

Comment: They have to be both be equal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93632/discussion-between-triode-and-mike-ross).

Comment: @Triode you can get the same width with grid system in bootstrap and as far as height is concern look at this [example](http://www.minimit.com/demos/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height)